# How to Validate Transaction id (TXN) during paypal checkout

Tags: php, mysql, paypal, payment

So i need to integrate PAYPAL checkout in my website. and i don't have much experience with Paypal integration. If you can help it will be really great. 
So I have followed through this
[Tutorial](http://www.codexworld.com/paypal-standard-payment-gateway-integration-php/)

I have created two PAYPAL sandbox accounts. One for Buyer and another for seller.
I am able to do payments with those.
But Problem is in success.php page
where i need to validate the payment.

What i did is checked if the Transaction ID already exists in database. but the problem is the success.php uses GET method and the transaction ID can be edited in the GET method. So changing transaction ID to anything (Random String) Will validate the condition that, Transaction ID doesn't exists in database and you can do payment.

So due to this the payment is marked as valid and balance is added to users database. Is there any way to check that the transaction ID is Valid Paypal TX id.

Thanks :)

Comment: Uh... I think this tutorial is kinda wrong. You are relying on the user to return to your success page to store the transaction information. What happens if the user doesn't go back to your success page after they do the transaction? Well then you are going to have a problem because the transaction will not be saved in your database.

Comment: but if they play with html code, and change success page then it's their problem.

Comment: I'm not referring to them messing with HTML. I'm talking about them not clicking on the link that goes back to your site. Even if you add the setting to automatically redirect them back to your site, something could happen where they do not reach your site. The correct or safer way to handle payments is to use PayPal IPN as mentioned at the end of the tutorial and outlined by jsabina.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't rely on the return page to validate the transaction.
What you receive via GET can be changed, the customer might close the page before or for connection problems never be redirected.
With PayPal standard you should use IPN to validate the payment
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/
there are info on their documentation and script examples online.
You need to setup a listener that will be called by paypal after the transaction is executed

Comment: Yes, IPN is the PayPal recommended way to fulfil orders, mainly because it is a robust and secure mechanism.

Comment: The PDT is just to provide an acknowledgement to the client, IF they get back to the site. PayPal recommends checking several IPN values for fraud, like receiver_email matches your primary PP email, and product code and price match, in addition to only sending the goods for one 'Completed' txn_status IPN message for the txn_id. Note that IPN handling is not trivial, but the PHP code example they give is rock solid.